# How to download batch of randomly named files

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, download-manager

I need to download a bunch of files from a website but I don't want to have to click on each file to add it to downloadall or whatever.

The structure of the website is as follows:

http://something.com/katalog/?get=Exclusive/group1/2012.09.03/

The directory has loads of randomly named files with .doc extensions.  I can't use the batch feature because the files don't start or end with the same characters e.g. 001...100.

Any ideas/

Comment: Is there an "index" page containing these links? If there is, many download add-ons allow starting all (or several) links at once. If there's no such page, is there any pattern of file naming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?from=getfirefox) and the [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) extension should be able to take care of this easily.